# Wireless Network Unclaimed: Is it wifi driver issue?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, 23.10

I bought this laptop(Dell latitude 5410) with windows installed and Wifi worked fine. I installed Ubuntu 18.0 on it, wifi did not work. I formatted everything and installed Ubuntu 23.10.0 on it and wifi still did not work. In settings it says wifi adapter not found. However, Bluetooth is working fine. I researched a lot and none of the solutions fixed the problem. Currently I'm connected through Ethernet but I need wifi. I'm a new ubuntu user and need your help.

**Things i've tried that did not work.**

- Tried *modprobe iwlwifi* (still shows unclaimed)

```
sudo lshw -C network
Output:
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:9133c000-9133ffff
```

- Updating kernel (from 6.5 to 6.8) (did not work so i reverted back to 6.5.0-24-generic)
- Installing bios updates
- Installing newer iwlwifi drivers
- installing *backport-iwlwifi-dkms* drivers (however this did not install fully as some modules become obsolete after kernel version 6.5.0)
- Installed linux-modules-extra.
- I did all the steps as mentioned in this [guide](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/intel-wifi.html).
- Tried rebooting without Ethernet connected. Tried disabling Bluetooth.
- I also tried manually installing wifi drivers ([Intel AX201](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html))from intel website.

After doing all this, I'm stumped and don't know what to do. please help. I've attached the Wireless Info Script.

I couldn't paste the output of wireless info script as HTML here bcs it was getting marked as spam.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/32CsWjfGpJ/